# Approaches to accurate 3d compass for finding specific locations

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps

Say an event is being hosted in a large building. There are 20 rooms which are quite difficult to find.

I want to develop an app which points you in the right direction of a specified room or shows on a 3-d map, the location of you, relative to this room. This obviously includes altitude as the building has many floors.

Now, I looked into GPS, which is not very accurate and also depends on the quality of the phone's GPS. I'm not sure if this is really an option for the accuracy I require.

I also looked into Bluetooth beacons, but it is apparently very difficult to add direction to this as well as distance. Plus, this is only accurate at around 20 meters, right?

What other alternatives are out there that I can research myself?

And which options can I definitely eliminate?

I am not looking for a heated debate over the best approach, I know this is against SO rules.

So just a few potential options is all I wasnt, so I can go and research them myself... maybe wifi or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS you can forget, there is no or very bad receivement indoors.

I would concentrate on blue tooth beacons. Apple provides such iBeacons, too. So  this can give you more information what is feasible.

The third possibility is magnetic field analysis, but i dont trust much that solutions. Altough there are demos and even an ios App (Indoor Atlas), this soultion has some drawbacks. Change of magnetic field after change in construction / furniture.